# A friend says that she will flip a coin 5 times?

Tags: binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

[image]

Where did we get 32?

I correctly understood that 10 is a product of 2 and 5 which in turn forms the desired number 32?

Comment: $2^5 = 2\times2\times2\times2\times2 = 32$

Comment: It's said right in the text: "$2^5=32$ possible outcomes." Each flip has two outcomes, and it's flipped five times ...

Comment: I clearly understood. The coin has two sides, which means two possible results, but we toss the coin 5 times. As a result, we have 2 possible outcomes combined with the flip times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 32 possible sequences of outcomes, because you have two values per coin (head vs tail) and 5 independent throws, so $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 = 32$ many outcomes in total by the product counting rule. Every coin flip **doubles** the number of outcomes.

There are $\binom{5}{3}=\frac{120}{6 \times 2}=10$ places where three heads can be thrown vs the two tails. So $10$ of the sequences (HHHTT, HHTHT, HHTTH, HTHHT, etc.) give you $\$30$ payout. So the probability is $\frac{10}{32}=\frac{5}{16}$, a little under a half.

Answer (score 1):

- $32$ is as stated in the solution of your problem the number of possible outcomes of this game. To count them all you could draw a tree, each layer of the tree representing the possible result from the flip of a coin and all the leaves representing the final 32 possible outcomes (of the type (hhhhh, hhhht, hhhth, hhhtt, etc.)
- $10$ represents the number of way you have, out of those 32 possible outcomes, to get 3 heads (and winning therefore 30$)

Dividing the latter by the former gives you the probability you want to compute.